# Spark SQL launches unequal number of jobs for identical queries

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables finance.movies and finance.dummytable_3.

- Both has been created using Spark SQL and their meta information is same
- Both has two files
- The total file size of **finance.movies is 312363** while that of **finance.dummytable_3 is 1209**
- But when I execute a simple "select *" on both the tables, **finance.dummytable_3 whose total file size is less execute 2 jobs** while **finance.movies executes only one job**. Screenshot follows.

```
hive> describe formatted finance.movies;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment

movieid                 int
title_movie             string
genres                  string

# Detailed Table Information
Database:               finance
Owner:                  root
CreateTime:             Thu Apr 16 02:18:51 EDT 2020
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://test.com:8020/GenNext_Finance_DL/Finance.db/movies
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE
Table Parameters:
        numFiles                2
        spark.sql.create.version        2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292
        spark.sql.sources.provider      parquet
        spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts       1
        spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0 {\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"movieid\",\"type\":\"integer\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"title_movie\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"genres\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}
        totalSize               312363
        transient_lastDdlTime   1587017931

# Storage Information
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
        path                    hdfs://test.com:8020/GenNext_Finance_DL/Finance.db/movies
        serialization.format    1
Time taken: 3.877 seconds, Fetched: 35 row(s)
```

```
hive> describe formatted finance.dummytable_3;
OK
# col_name              data_type               comment

colname1                string
colname2                string
colname3                string

# Detailed Table Information
Database:               finance
Owner:                  root
CreateTime:             Wed Apr 15 02:40:18 EDT 2020
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://test.com:8020/GenNext_Finance_DL/Finance.db/dummytable_3
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE
Table Parameters:
        numFiles                2
        spark.sql.create.version        2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292
        spark.sql.sources.provider      parquet
        spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts       1
        spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0 {\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"colName1\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"colName2\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"colName3\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}
        totalSize               1209
        transient_lastDdlTime   1586932818

# Storage Information
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
        path                    hdfs://test.com:8020/GenNext_Finance_DL/Finance.db/dummytable_3
        serialization.format    1
Time taken: 0.373 seconds, Fetched: 35 row(s)
```

When I execute the following query the number of jobs being executed is 2

```
spark-sql --master yarn --name spark_load_test -e "select * from finance.dummytable_3 limit 2;"
```

[image]

While when I execute the following query, the number of job being executed is just one. Despite both the tables having two files and identical struture.

```
spark-sql --master yarn --name spark_load_test -e "select * from finance.movies limit 2;"
```

[image]

Comment: can you re-run top confirm this again, at another time?

Comment: @thebluephantom I have been doing this for days with various permutations. But this seems to be the consistent behavior, its just that I am unable to find the reason why?

Comment: interesting, hard to say from a distance...

Comment: can you please execute these commands - hdfs dfs -ls -h hdfs://test.com:8020/GenNext_Finance_DL/Finance.db/movies
hdfs dfs -ls -h hdfs://test.com:8020/GenNext_Finance_DL/Finance.db/dummytable_3
 & show us output here ?

Comment: Please run an explain plan for these two queries. i.e. `df = spark.sql("select * from finance.dummytable_3 limit 2") \n df.explain(True)`

Comment: what is the size of each file in these two table? By any chance is it possible that one of the file of the table finance.movie has no/zero data?

Comment: I would check if my datanodes are imbalanced. This might happen when some are full, and the admins have provisioned some new datanodes to be able to handle the load (see [HADOOP-1652](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1652) ).